# Is there is possible to assign different types of values in one enum in swift

Tags: swift

```
enum Hotel{
case hotelName: "Raddisson"
case hotelCost: 200
case offer: 0.02
}
```

How should assign the multiple types in the enum?

Comment: Read the section named "Associated values" in the Swift Programming Guide.

Comment: Looks like you just want a `struct Hotel` with `name`, `cost` & `offer` properties. If you want to have a particular set of default values, you can add one or more `static` properties – compare http://stackoverflow.com/q/42954148/2976878

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a struct here, for example:

```
struct Hotel {
    let hotelName: String
    let hotelCost: NSDecimalNumber
    let offer: NSDecimalNumber
}
```

To have an enum with multiple values you could do this using associated values:

```
enum Hotel {
    case standard(name: String, cost: NSDecimalNumber, offer: NSDecimalNumber)
    case extended(name: String, cost: NSDecimalNumber, offer: NSDecimalNumber, discount: NSDecimalNumber)
}
```

An example of how to extract the values from the above enum is:

```
let hotel = Hotel.standard(name: "Hotel", cost: 50, offer: 10)

if case let Hotel.standard(name, cost, offer) = hotel {
    print (name, cost, offer)
}

switch hotel {
case let .standard(name, cost, offer):
    print (name, cost, offer)
case let .extended(name, cost, offer, discount):
    print (name, cost, offer, discount)
}
```

Comment: I am beginner for swift language.Thank you for your valuable comment

Comment: enum StarHotel{
    case hotel(rating:Int,cost: Int,days: Int,offer: Double)
} 
var hotelPark = StarHotel.hotel(rating: 5, cost: 90, days: 3, offer: 0.2)                   How should I access individually eg. print(hotelPark.rating)  likewise ??

Comment: I have updated my answer with an example. While this does work, I think for the example you have given, a struct or class would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is not possible to have cases of an enum of different types. An enum can have some `raw type`, but that type is same for all the cases. Below is the example of enum having raw type `String`

```
enum Hotel: String {
  case hotelName: "Raddisson"
  case hotelCost: "200"
  case offer: "0.02"
}
```